# Зафиксировать кнопку по левому краю

Tags: html, css

Необходимо зафиксировать кнопку по левому краю. У блока `position: fixed;`. Почему-то `left: 0;` не работает.

```
<a href="http://cegit/ova/knowledge_base" target="_blank">
        <div class="knowledge-base-button">
            <div class="rotate">Сундук продавца</div>
            <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64 />
 </div>
    </a>

  .knowledge-base-button {
position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
top: 250px;
left: 0;

background: #f06420;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 10px;
height: auto;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
 }
.knowledge-base-button .rotate {
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 2;    
}
.knowledge-base-button img {
margin: 2px;
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg));
-webkit-transition:all 400ms;
-moz-transition:all 400ms;
-o-transition:all 400ms;
transition:all 400ms;
 }
.knowledge-base-button:hover img {
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

}
```

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/syyeadgg/)

Как прижать фиксированную кнопку к левому краю ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.knowledge-base-button {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0;
    background: #f06420;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
  
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.knowledge-base-button .rotate {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 2;
}

.knowledge-base-button img {
    margin: 2px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg));
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    -o-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

.knowledge-base-button:hover img {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://cegit/ova/knowledge_base" target="_blank">
    <div class="knowledge-base-button">
        <div class="rotate">кнопка</div>
        <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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"
        />

    </div>
</a>
```